# How to fix errors with Angular Materials not working

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

- When attempting to use angular materials in my angular application,
  they don't seem to be working, on googling the problem I've seen a
  lot of similar problems where the solution was "import the relevant
  material" however I believe I already have imported the materials in
  both necessary places in the imports in app.module.ts.

> the error I am receiving is currently:

```
"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-checkbox' is not a known element:
 - If 'mat-checkbox' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
 - If 'mat-checkbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<mat-checkbox>Check me!</mat-checkbox>
<button mat-button>Click me!</button>
"): ng:///PagesModule/ExamplePageComponent.html@0:0"
```

- I have installed using npm: @angular/materials 6.10.3
  @angular/animations 6.10.3 @angular/cdk 6.10.3

  I have already tried adding CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to the component
  but to no avail. If I change the html to attempt to use different
  components from angular materials I get a similar error message
  corresponding to whichever component I am attempting to use. None of
  the Angular Materials work. I have followed several tutorials and
  cannot seem to find the root of my problem.

> app.module.ts

```
    ...import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
    import {    GestureConfig,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule, 
    } from '@angular/material';
    @NgModule({
    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxPermissionsModule.forRoot(),
    PartialsModule,
    CoreModule,
    OverlayModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {metaReducers}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument(),
    AuthModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot(),
    InlineSVGModule.forRoot(),
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    ],
    exports: [],
    providers: [
    AuthService,
    LayoutConfigService,
    LayoutRefService,
    MenuConfigService,
    PageConfigService,
    KtDialogService,
    DataTableService,
    SplashScreenService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    export class AppModule {
    }
```

> example-page.component.html

```
    <mat-checkbox>Check me!</mat-checkbox>
    <button mat-button>Click me!</button>
```

> example-page.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
    selector: 'kt-example-page',
    templateUrl: './example-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./example-page.component.scss']
    })
    export class ExamplePageComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add it to exports in your `app.module.ts`:

```
exports: [MatCheckboxModule]
```